# 5-Year Multi Entry UK Visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, south-african-citizens, long-term

We are a South African couple with 5-year multi entry visas expiring in February 2024. For how long do we need to be out of the UK before we can return again? We intend spending the maximum of 6 months there on each visit if possible. We intend buying our own property there.

Comment: @Tom Dunn There is no hard and fast rule regarding time in/out out of the UK. The typical advice is to spend at least the same amount of time in your home country as in the UK and avoid a pattern of travel suggesting that you are trying to live in the UK through frequent or successive visits.  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules App V4.2 “(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home”.  You may also be liable for UK tax if you spend more than 183 days a year in the UK

Comment: https://www.litrg.org.uk/tax-guides/migrants/residence-and-domicile/when-someone-resident-uk